# Checkbox programming visual studio C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, checkbox

Hope you all having a great day

I have a problem while programming a checkbox in Microsoft visual studio .windows Form application. My project is about designing a font dialog box see the photo pls help. when I check the checkbox it work but when unchecked nothing happen to the test label example: i have a label called Test Sample and 3 checkboxs one of them is bold the other is italic and last one is underline.when i click on all of the three the test lable changed but when uncheck one of them nothing happens 
Thank you for your time..

Comment: Are we supposed to guess what your code looks like? You should probably provide a [mcve].

Comment: Yeah i want to know how it will look like

Comment: share your code if you need help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing you want to have an event to trigger when your checkbox unchecked.

you can try this.

```
private void checkBox1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)  
{  
   // The CheckBox control's Text property is changed each time the   
   // control is clicked, indicating a checked or unchecked state.  
   if (checkBox1.Checked)  
   {  
      checkBox1.Text = "Checked";  
   }  
   else  
   {  
     checkBox1.Text = "Unchecked";  
   }  
}
```

OR

```
private void checkBox1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)  
{  
   switch(checkBox1.CheckState)  
   {  
      case CheckState.Checked:  
         // Code for checked state.  
         break;  
      case CheckState.Unchecked:  
         // Code for unchecked state.  
         break;  
      case CheckState.Indeterminate:  
         // Code for indeterminate state.  
         break;  
   }  
}
```

Note: You can Take a look at the documentation at [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-respond-to-windows-forms-checkbox-clicks)

Comment: Thank you for your replying...its useful answer but if you could help because i have 3 checkboxs its complicated to deal with them in the same time to be bold italic and underline the problem with the unchecked state  please help

Comment: @user9039175 I cant understand, which part is difficult? you have 3 checkboxs, you can add the logic in each of them. Which part is difficult for you.

Comment: The problem is that i cant upload photo yet to make it understandable

Comment: @user9039175 I need to see the code. I cant understand exactly which part is the problem. Now you can find out exactly when your checkboxs are checked or unchecked so it should be easy to handle the events and do what is required for uploading the image